# Closeness wrt Hausdorff distance implies closeness of the measure of the two sets

Tags: hausdorff-distance

Given two measurable disjoint subsets $A,B\subset\Bbb R^n$, which are surfaces of some dimension $k<n$ (e.g. two curves in $\Bbb R^2$ or in $\Bbb R^3$) of finite $k$-dim Lebesgue measure such that
$$
d_H(A,B)<\epsilon
$$
where $d_H$ is the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#:%7E:text=The%20Hausdorff%20distance%20is%20the,point%20in%20the%20other%20set.).

Can we deduce that
$$
|\mu_k(A)-\mu_k(B)|<\epsilon
$$
?

Comment: In your title, you want to say "Hausdorff distance", not "Hausdorff measure".

Comment: No, not with the same $\epsilon$.  In fact, you can't bound it at all (easy example with $k=0$)

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take $k = 1$ and $n=2$. Let $A = [0] \times \{i/N \mid i = 0,1,\ldots, N\}$ and $B = ([0] \times [0,1]) \backslash A$.
Then $d_H(A,B)  \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$, but $A$ has $1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $0$ and $B$ has $1$.

Comment: $A$ isn't of dimension 1, but it is easy to thicken it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give my example.

The $0$-dimensional measure is just the usual counting measure.  In $\mathbb{R}$, consider $A=\{0\}$ and $B$ a finite set of points in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]-\{0\}$.  Then $d_H(A,B)\leq\epsilon$ but $\#A=1$ and $\#B$ is arbitrary.

Now you can take product with $[0,1]^k\times\{0\}^{n-k-1}$ to get example for any $k<n$.